# Configuring the Datatables List Search

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to simultaneously limit the Datatables "global" list search to a particular column while preserving individual column searching in a basic HTML table? I want to hide two specific columns so they will populate two drop-downs to serve as rudimentary filters and limit the main search field to the first column. Unfortunately, I've only found documentation that either disables searching for the entire list or in specific columns using "columnDef()". If used to disable searching in a specific column, the latter tool prevents the targeted fields from being searchable by individual column search drop-downs [demonstrated here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html). Does any one know if this is possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want drop-down search for specific column in datatable as in the  demonstrated link above mentioned by you?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to leverage the individual column drop-downs as basic filters using content from hidden column(s). I'm using a custom drop-down located above the table while the column feeding that drop-down is simply hidden from view. The problem is, if I disable searching for that column so the global list search doesn't search the hidden column using the columnDefs() property, then the drop-down will no longer work either, if that makes sense.